# XML to HTML Generator with Style template

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, html-generation

What is a best way for generatring html files from xml data using style template ?
I know about XSLT and XML but I need to generate html files using style template(XSLT/CSS).

For example:

```
 XML+ XSLT/CSS + images+ javascript -->  Tool  --> html files.
```

Why I want to generate html files is because of browser that i am using says "bad mimetype" when we try to open xml (styled with xslt).

Any kind of direction or tool implemenation suggestion (in java, php, c++) is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after investigating I have found best solution for this tool.

XML + XSLT + images + javascript/CSS -> Tool -> html site

Best way to implement this tool is using API based on XSLT 2.0 processor/transformer; in java implementations are available in different ways: e.g. Saxon is being widely used.